# BibTeX with Diplomarbeit and Eprint

Tags: bibtex, arxiv

I found it a bit challenging to write a bibliography with Diplomarbeit and Eprints.

From looking in [http://arxiv.org](https://arxiv.org/help/hypertex/bibstyles/) I would need to use their `bst` style, which I don't know how to install local and probably does not support Diplomarbeit, rather Master thesis.

From the other hand, `dinat.bst` support Diplomarbeit, but does not support Eprints.

How could I combine both worlds in one BibTeX?

I am using

```
\documentclass[ pdftex, a4paper ]{scrbook}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

**EDIT**

Diplomarbeit is equivalent to Master thesis, but its called Diplomarbeit, so if i would write in my bibliography Master thesis, it would be incorrect. I used  `plainnatdin.bst` but for having Diplomarbeit, i needed to moved to `dinat.bst`. I tried both with the following lines in my bibtex file

```
 archivePrefix = "arXiv",
 eprint        = "0707.3168",
 primaryClass  = "hep-th",
```

with out success.

I am using Gentoo (Linux) with `dev-texlive/texlive-latex v2011`

Comment: Please provide some more information about the documentclass, TeX distribution, and other aspects of your LaTeX setup. What is "Diplomarbeit": a documentclass, a package, a bst file? Separately, I wasn't aware of arxiv.org requiring the use of a certain bst file -- or, for that matter, any bst file at all.

Answer (score 2):

For the problem with 'Diplomarbeit' as a BibTex-Item I use the solution if the `babelbib`-Package.

Insert

```
\useopackage{babelbib}
\usepackage[english,german]{babel}
\bibliographystyle{babalpha}
```

where the 'babalpha' is just an example, but here the 'bab...'-Styles have to be used.
Now you have to add a field 'language' to every (!) item in your bib-File, for example:

```
@mastersthesis{bib:dipme,
author = {Someone},
title= {something},
school = {somewhere},
year = {2012},
language = {german},
}
```

Now, it will not say, 'masters thesis' but 'Diplomarbeit'. With the field set to 'language= {english}' you keep 'masters thesis' (for this item).

As for the Eprints: I have no good idea. Whenever I am in a similar situation I just use the miscelaneous-type

Comment: it seems that the order of the packages is importent. i placed `\usepackage[english,german]{babel}` before `\useopackage{babelbib}` and i got some problems. In addition i needed to use \selectlanguage{english}, other wise i saw all the titles in german....

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `type` attribute to your bibtex entry

```
@MastersThesis{Behlendorf:Thesis:2019,
    author   = {Michael Behlendorf},
    title    = {{Vertrauenswürdige Speicherung von Ortsdaten in Blockchains zur Verifikation von Ereignissen}},
    school   = {Technische Universität Braunschweig},
    address  = {Deutschland},
    year     = {2019},
    type     = {Masterarbeit}
}
```

Will give you "Masterarbeit" in the references.

[image: Masterarbeit]

```
@MastersThesis{Behlendorf:Thesis:2019,
    author   = {Michael Behlendorf},
    title    = {{Vertrauenswürdige Speicherung von Ortsdaten in Blockchains zur Verifikation von Ereignissen}},
    school   = {Technische Universität Braunschweig},
    address  = {Deutschland},
    year     = {2019},
    type     = {Diplomarbeit}
}
```

Will give you "Diplomarbeit" in the references.

[image: Diplomarbeit]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please - as usual here -- add an compilable small tex code resulting in the shown image?